# How does EOS validate signature and find that signature canonical or not?

Tags: nodeos

I am signing transactions by third party service, but sometimes i get signature is not canonical. My question is what algorithm does EOS use for validation signature and check is it canonical or not?

I got exception like this
{"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":10,"name":"assert_exception","what":"Assert Exception","details":[{"message":"is_canonical( c ): signature is not canonical","file":"elliptic_secp256k1.cpp","line_number":164,"method":"public_key"},{"message":"","file":"transaction.cpp","line_number":135,"method":"get_signature_keys"}]}}

Comment: Someone asked this question once before, but I can't find that anymore. Can you explain what you mean by canonical?

Comment: Signature can be produced 4 times. But only one of them is canonical. I am not a big expert. But when third  party service is signing transaction i got message from eos network signature is not canonical

Comment: {"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":10,"name":"assert_exception","what":"Assert Exception","details":[{"message":"is_canonical( c ): signature is not canonical","file":"elliptic_secp256k1.cpp","line_number":164,"method":"public_key"},{"message":"","file":"transaction.cpp","line_number":135,"method":"get_signature_keys"}]}}